# py file executable is using a lot of my CPU

Tags: python, executable, python-3.7, cpu-usage

I wrote a python code to type whatever I tell him to type and it always runs in the background and takes too much of my CPU.
Do you have any idea to make it use less CPU?
My os is windows 10

Comment: There is nothing to show, I use a while true command to always listen and when it gets something it types it

Comment: I'm assuming there is no time.sleep() in the while loop anywhere.

Comment: no,why would be? @AnirudhPanchangam

Comment: speech recogniton module @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0):

If your Python code seems simple and is using lots of CPU time, you probably have an infinite loop in your code.

For example:

```
x = 1
while x > 0:
    x = x + 1
```

will happily run forever and take up a lot of CPU time.  Calling `os.sleep()` will not.  Your best bet is use the debugger.   If your program were named `program.py`, you would run it with a debugger like `python -m pdb program.py`.  Use 's', or the step command to execute your code line by line.

Comment: assuming this will work how to convert it into exe file and running it with the debugger?